# error with javascript back

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a issue with sending back on my login forgot password section at http://www.webstitcher.com/bootstrap_barelogin

For whatever reason it says document no longer available, although it works for the register section fine every time.

See anything wrong?

```
 if (isset($_POST['forgot'])){ ?>
               <form name="stoop" method="POST">
                   <div class="panel panel-info">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title"> Forgot Password/User?</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">


             <label class="sr-only" for="E-mail">E-mail</label>

           <input type="text" name="forgot" id="forgot" class="field" value="" size="23" placeholder="Account Email Address"  />
             <div class="row">   <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">   <input type="submit" name="stoop" value="Send E-mail" class=" btn btn-info" /></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                    <button type="button" onclick="history.back();" class="btn btn-success">Back</button>
                    </div></div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: where is the error on given link it is working fine at my side.

Comment: hey!! it's working fine.there is no error...